Singularity of $L$ and $K$ operators
In the book the Method of Moments in EM by Gibson Third edition page 47 is writing that $L$ and $K$ operator have different behaviors in the singularity region, where $K$ diverges and $L$ is well-behaved.
$L$ is defined as $$[1+\dfrac{1}{k^2} \nabla \nabla \cdot ]\int G(r,r')X(r')dr'.$$
$K$ is defined as $$ \nabla \times \int G(r,r')X(r')dr'.$$
Where $X(r')$ is the source (Electric or magnetic currents $J$,$M$).
Why is $L$ well behaved? After all it contains the gradient of the divergence of the green function, it's supposed to be the integral of $\large\frac{1}{\Delta r^5}$. Comparing to the K operator, that contains the curl of the green function it's about $\large\frac{1}{\Delta r^3}$, where $\Delta r\equiv |r-r'|$
